# Select and extract text from PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf

I am building an application in IOS to read a PDF document and then need to mark or select some text for to assing to a NSString and then to do something with the selected text. In the Appstore, "PDF EXPERT" get it very easily. Anyone know if you can do through any method, property or Framework Apple or know any other system to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.